# Нужна помощь по коду PHP

Tags: php

Делаю лабораторную, сижу уже около нескольких часов и не могу выйти на трапу исправления. Код запускается, но не работает форма проверки "невед. полей".
Извиняюсь, если неграмотно объяснил что-то. При вопросе, постараюсь более четко и грамотно ответить.

Код

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Контактна інформація</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php

if (!$submit): /* Початок основної програми*/
?>
    <h3>Будь-ласка, введіть інформацію про себе</h3>
    Поля з <b>*</b> обов'язкові для заповнення
    <p>
      <?php
print_form("","","","","","");
else:
check_form($_POST['f_name'], $_POST['l_name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['zip'], $_POST['object']);
endif;
/* Об'являємо деякі функції*/
function print_form ($f_name, $l_name, $email, $zip, $object){
?>
        <form action="index2.php" method="post">
          <table cellspasing="2" cellpedding="2" border="1">
            <tr>
              <td>Ім'я</td>
              <td><input name="f_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $f_name ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Прізвище<b>*</b></td>
              <td><input name="l_name" type="text" value="<?php print $l_name ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Email адреса<b>*</b></td>
              <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php print $email ?>">

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Поштовий індекс<b>*</b></td>
              <td><input name="zip" type="text" value="<?php print $zip ?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Улюблений предмет</td>
              <td><input name="object" type="text" value="<?php print $object ?>">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Надіслати">
          <input type="reset" value="Відмінити">
        </form>
        <?
}
function check_form ($f_name, $l_name, $email, $zip, $object) {
    if (!$l_name||!$email||!$zip):echo "<h3>Помилка у заповненні форми!</h3>";
    if (!isset($_POST['l_name'])) {
    echo "<h3>Ви не заповнили поле <b>Прізвище</b></h3>";
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['email'])){
    echo "<h3>Ви не заповнили поле <b>Email адреса</b></h3>";
    }
    if (!isset($_POST['zip'])){
    echo "<h3>Ви не заповнили поле <b>Поштовий індекс</b></h3>";
    }
    print_form($f_name, $l_name, $email, $zip, $object);
    else:
    confirm_form($f_name, $l_name, $email, $zip, $object);
    endif;
    }
function confirm_form ($f_name, $l_name, $email, $zip, $object){
?>
          <h2>Дякуємо! Слідуюча інформація була успішно надіслана
          </h2>
          <b>Контактна інформація</b>
          <? echo "<br>$f_name $l_name<br>$email<br>Поштовий індекс:$zip<br>Улюблений предмет:$object\n";

}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

К

```html
if (!$submit): /* Початок основної програми*/
?>
```

Требовалось добавить

```
array_key_exist
if (!array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)):
```

Спустя долгое время получилось все таки решить.